# Expect Script ( Expect Minus Sign from Junos Router Show | Compare)

Tags: expect, router

I have some problem with my script, i want to expect minus sign after expect send command show | compare into junos router.

Need someone help me..

Script

```
expect "#"
send "show | compare\r"

set total_error_minus 0
expect -- "-"
incr total_error_minus
```

Example Result

```
[edit]<br>
telco@junos_lab# show | compare<br>
[edit interfaces em0]<br>
- description B;<br>
+ description C;<br>
[edit interfaces em0 unit 1]<br>
- description A;<br>
+ description D;<br>

[edit]<br>
telco@junos_lab#  <br>
```

How to detect and count minus sign after show | compare command using expect script ?

Comment: Don't u need send `enter` key ? Doesn't it need to be a `send "show | compare\r"` ?

Comment: Owh, i think i missed to put "\r" , thanks dinesh

Answer (score 0):

Use the flag `--` to specify any option-like arguments.

```
expect -- "-"
```

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, absolutely what i want. but if show | compare result as below : [edit] pijan@junos_lab# show | compare [edit interfaces em0] - description B; + description C; [edit interfaces em0 unit 1] - description A; + description D; how can i incr minus sign in expect script ?

Comment: Update this info in the original post. Couldn't read code properly.

Comment: Dinesh,Done as request

Answer (score 0):

You need your expect statement to go into a loop:

```
set total_error_minus 0
send "show | compare\r"
expect {
    -- "-" {incr total_error_minus; exp_continue}
    "telco@junos_lab# "
}
# continue with script ...
```

Comment: Hi, i have try this code, but problem still cannot resolve this problem. expect minus sign not working

Comment: Working after remove ; incr total_error_minus and script as below .. expect {  -- "-" {  incr total_error_minus exp_continue } "telco@junos_lab# "  } , thanks glenn jackman.. nice

Comment: @SparK, The suggested edit actually introduces a syntax error. I rolled back.